# Как правильно отправлять много запросов? Ошибка 429

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Нужно отправлять на сервер 2000+ GET запросов, но после 20 приходит ошибка 429.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ошибка 429: Too Many Requests — клиент попытался отправить слишком
>   много запросов за короткое время, что может указывать, например, на
>   попытку DDoS-атаки.

Вам нужно снизить число одновременных\последовательных запросов, проставьте таймауты например.